# Will reformatting my computer with windows 8 wipeout both internal hard drives?

Tags: windows-8, formatting

Will reformatting my computer with windows 8 wipeout both internal hard drives?
Main one is C:/, and secondary one is D:/

If it only wipes out primary drive, will D:/ remain unchanged, and be a good candidate to store valuable workspaces/data/music?

Comment: This entirely depends on if you have 2 partitions or 2 physical disks.

Comment: I believe I have two physical disks, how can I confirm this? So I take it yes it'll wipeout both if it's two partitions, no it won't if it's two separate physical entities.

Comment: Open your computer and verify you have 2 seperate HDDs.

Comment: @Ramhound if the C partition is big enough to host win8 then it does not matter if there are two separate HDDs. Win8 does ask you where you want to install, so even with one HDD you can preserve data on drive D.  The answer is the same if you have two partitions or two physical disks.

Comment: @Deesbek - To somebody without the technical experience of installing Windows, it makes a difference, because its very easy to make choose the option that wipes the entire disk instead of a single partition.  So it makes a difference in my eyes and how I planned on answering the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows itself will not reformat multiple partitions unless you are trying to do something custom prior or during the installation. It will just install into the partition you selected as the destination during the install without touching the other partitions or drives. So your D: partition is safe from Windows (but maybe not you :-) )

To find out your drive/partition configuration, run the "Disk Management" dialog from the control panel. Or just run "diskmgmt.msc". This will show if C and D are on the same drive or not.

Of course, anytime you have something valuable on a drive, you would **always** make and have a backup before trying something like rebuilding a system that could wipe out those files.